# Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context when I try updating my viewmodel

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am having some trouble with a linq query I am trying to write.

I am trying to use the repository pattern without to much luck. Basically I have a list of transactions and a 2nd list which contains the description field that maps against a field in my case StoreItemID

```
    public static IList<TransactionViewModel> All()
    {
        var result = (IList<TransactionViewModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Transactions"];
        if (result == null)
        {
            var rewardTypes = BusinessItemRepository.GetItemTypes(StoreID);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Transactions"] = 
                result =
              (from item in new MyEntities().TransactionEntries
                 select new TransactionViewModel()
                                   {
                            ItemDescription = itemTypes.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.StoreItemID==item.StoreItemID).ItemDescription,
                     TransactionDate = item.PurchaseDate.Value,
                     TransactionAmount = item.TransactionAmount.Value,
                                   }).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }


     public static List<BusinessItemViewModel>GetItemTypes(int storeID)
    {
        var result = (List<BusinessItemViewModel>)HttpContext.Current.Session["ItemTypes"];
        if (result == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["ItemTypes"] = result =
                (from items in new MyEntities().StoreItems
                 where items.IsDeleted == false && items.StoreID == storeID
                 select new BusinessItemViewModel()
                 {
                     ItemDescription = items.Description,
                     StoreID = items.StoreID,
                     StoreItemID = items.StoreItemID
                 }).ToList();
        }
        return result;
```

However I get this error

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyMVC.ViewModels.BusinessItemViewModel'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

I know its this line of code as if I comment it out it works ok

```
ItemDescription = itemTypes.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.StoreItemID==item.StoreItemID).ItemDescription,
```

How can I map ItemDescription against my list of itemTypes?

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line has a problem:

```
 ItemDescription = itemTypes.FirstOrDefault(r=>r.StoreItemID==item.StoreItemID)
                            .ItemDescription,
```

Since you are using `FirstOrDefault` you will get `null` as default value for a reference type if there is no item that satifies the condition, then you'd get an exception when trying to access `ItemDescription` - either use `First()` if there always will be at least one match or check and define a default property value for `ItemDescription` to use if there is none:

```
 ItemDescription = itemTypes.Any(r=>r.StoreItemID==item.StoreItemID) 
                           ? itemTypes.First(r=>r.StoreItemID==item.StoreItemID)
                                      .ItemDescription
                           : "My Default",
```

Comment: Hi Broken Glass thanks for your help. Still the same problem tho, I have put a breakpoint on and checked the StoreItemID match and also checked for ItemDescription which is there however still the same problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: what type is `ItemDescription` ? I had assumed `string` - the problem doesn't seem to be in the code you shared then

Comment: Yes its a string. If I try your code outside of trying to populate my view model using something like var something = itemTypes.Any(r=>r.StoreItemID==14) 
                           ? itemTypes.First(r=>r.StoreItemID==14)
                                      .ItemDescription
                           : "My Default"

Comment: Hi BrokenGlass no not yet :( I have updated the code to try explain it better

Answer (score 1):

If itemTypes is IEnumerable then it can't be used in your query (which is what the error message is telling you), because the query provider doesn't know what to do with it. So assuming the that itemTypes is based on a table in the same db as TransactionEntities, then you can use a join to achieve the same goal:

```
using (var entities = new MyEntities())
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Transactions"] = result =
                (from item in new entities.TransactionEntries
                 join itemType in entities.ItemTypes on item.StoreItemID equals itemType.StoreItemID
                 select new TransactionViewModel()
                 {
                     ItemDescription = itemType.ItemDescription,
                     TransactionDate = item.PurchaseDate.Value,
                     TransactionAmount = item.TransactionAmount.Value,
                     CustomerName = rewards.CardID//TODO: Get customer name

                 }).ToList();
}
```

I don't know the structure of your database, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error due a nullable integer in my LINQ query.
Adding a check within my query it solved my problem.

query with problem:

```
var x = entities.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Obj_Id.Equals(y.OBJ_ID));
```

query with problem solved:

```
var x = entities.MyObjects.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Obj_Id.HasValue && s.Obj_Id.Value.Equals(y.OBJ_ID));
```