# linq query only headers that have details

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am trying to get only the headers that have a details using this Lambda statement

```
list = list.Where(c=> c.CustomerSalesPeople.Count>0);
```

but i am getting a null exception when I try to return the results

```
return list.OrderBy(c => c.CustomerName).ToList();
```

I have stepped through the code and see the null exception is generated right after I executed the first statement.  Is there a better way to accomplish this.

**EDIT**

I tried the suggestions and i was still getting a null value.  I figured I would try to explain better.  I need a Lambda expression that matches this Query

```
    SELECT *
  FROM [customer]
  where customer_record_id in (select distinct(customer_id)from customer_sales_person)
```

Comment: Is it linq to objects/sql/entities?

Comment: its linq to objects.  they are llblgen Entities.  LLBLGen is the ORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list = list.Where(c=>c.CustomerSalesPeople.Count>0).SingleOrDefault();

if(list!=null)
  return list.OrderBy(c=>c.CustomerName).ToList();

return list;
```

or if you think, `CustomerSalesPeople` can be null then you can do this:

```
list = list.Where(c=>(c.CustomerSalesPeople==null) ||(c.CustomerSalesPeople.Count>0));

if(list!=null)
  return list.OrderBy(c=>c.CustomerName).ToList();

return list;
```

also you can look at `.DefaultIfEmpty()` extension.

Linq provides excellent extension methods to counter when empty result set is found.
here they are:

1. [.FirstOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886796/linq-firstordefault)
2. [.DefaultIfEmpty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854181/defaultifempty-in-linq)
3. [.SingleOrDefault()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745691/linq-when-to-use-singleordefault-vs-firstordefault-with-filtering-criteria)

## UPDATE:

do this:

```
   List<int> uniqueIds= listOfCustomerSalesPerson.Select(s=>s.Id).ToList().Distinct();
   var requireListOfCustomers = GetAllCustomers().Where(s=>uniqueIds.Contains(s.id);
```

you can also embed these two separate calls in one though. but depending upon kind of data provider you are using, it might give you an error like,"[use only primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208194/only-primitive-types-such-as-int32-string-and-guid-are-supported-in-this-c)".hence the separate list of ids.

for instance, if you are using EntityFramework 5.0 and SQL Server, you can do this.

```
myDbContext db= new myDbContext();
var requiredList = db.Customers.Where(s=>
                               (s.CustomerSalesPeople ==null)
                               ||
                               (s.CustomerSalesPeople.Select(o=>o.Id).Contains(s.Id))
                               ).ToList();
```

I've assumed, Customer contains `List<CustomerSalesPeople>` , it can be `db.CustomerSalesPeople` otherwise

Comment: I changed the Select to Any and it worked perfectly.  Dont think i was aware of passing the parent variable s to the subquery as a parameter.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have null elements in your collection. Try to check nulls in where statement

```
return list != null ? 
   list.Where(c=> c!=null && c.CustomerSalesPeople.Count>0).
   OrderBy(c => c.CustomerName).ToList()
   :null;
```